# How can i build a FatJar with gradle (Without the depricated functions)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, fatjar

I am trying to create a FatJar with local .jar's. However, I have only found tutorials and guides in which the described methods like "compile" are deprecated.

What is the newest and best way to do something like this?

Need the finished .jar (with all depenecies) to run it on a remote server.

Comment:  Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help you getting some attention, may I ask which Gradle version you're using, and what exactly you mean by local jars? You may also want to post at least the relevant parts of your `build.gradle`.

Comment: yeah exactly , i assumed he is using groovy and considered both versions 5 to 7 , and above 7 .

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have since solved my problem with the answer below. I will be more detailed with the next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am assuming your not using kotlin because you did not mentioned any related info .
You can create your own task to do so

```java
task createfatJar(type: Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'full.package.path.Main'
  }
  archiveClassifier = "all"
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
  with jar
}
```

if your using the latest version , probably +7 you need to add `duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'` and remove the `configurations.compile.collect`

Am using 6.9 but it should look like the following

```java
task createfatJar(type: Jar) {
  duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'full.package.path.Main'
  }
  archiveClassifier = "all"
  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
  with jar
}
```

Hope this work if your using version 7 and higher .

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked well with this.

Comment: Your most welcome . glad i helped .